Can't fetch the following of tumblr accounts using the api
I wanted to create a python script that fetches the following/followers of specified tumblr usernames/username and exports it to a .json file. The problem is, every account except for mine can't be fetched and I get the error 403, aka Forbidden.
Here was my code:
import json
import pytumblr

# Authenticate via OAuth
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
  'Redacted',
  'Redacted',
  'Redacted',
  'Redacted'
)

def fetch_followers(username):
    # Fetch the following list
    following = client.followers(username)
    return following

def save_to_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    usernames = ['redacted']  # Replace with actual usernames
    all_following = {}

    for username in usernames:
        all_following[username] = fetch_followers(username)

    save_to_json(all_following, 'following.json')

And the output .json:
{
    "redacted": {
        "meta": {
            "status": 403,
            "msg": "Forbidden"
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "title": "Forbidden",
                "code": 0,
                "detail": "Something flubbed. Try again."
            }
        ],
        "response": []
    }
}

I tried checking the tumblr api docs but there didn't seem to be anything I could find that allieviates the issue. I expected to get the followers/following of the blog, but that didn't happen. Any help, please? I tried to use this website as best as I could. Thank you for your patience!
